# Vb.NET - GetEnumerator on a Custom Template class

Tags: vb.net, ienumerable

I've got a generic class build like this

```
Public Class TabellaCustom(Of myType, TValue) Implements IEnumerable(Of TValue)
Private mKey As myType
Private mContenuto As TValue
```

...

```
Public Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of TValue) Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TValue).GetEnumerator
        Return DirectCast(mContenuto, IEnumerator(Of TValue))
End Function
```

when I do something like this

```
dim Color as new ColorsEnumerable
Dim test(0) As StampeCommonFunctions.TabellaCustom(Of Color, String)
test(0) = New StampeCommonFunctions.TabellaCustom(Of Color, String)(Color.Red, "Red")

test.GetEnumerator()
```

I got an error:

```
 Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1[System.String]'.
```

How can I solve this error? I must specify the type of object inside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `mContenuto` is a string, and you're trying to cast it into an `IEnumerator(Of String)`, but the `string` class does not implement `IEnumerator(Of String)`.

That's what the exception is telling you.

Your class seems to just hold two values (`mKey`, `mContenuto`), why do you want to implement `IEnumerable<T>` at all? It seems there's no need to this...

---

You could nonetheless implement `GetEnumerator` like this:

```
Public Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of TValue) Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TValue).GetEnumerator
    Return {Me.mContenuto}.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator()
End Function

Private Function GetEnumerator1() As System.Collections.IEnumerator Implements System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
    Return GetEnumerator()
End Function
```

This works by creating an single-element array out of `mContenuto` and returning its `Enumerator`.

Comment: This is just a case for example; I need this type of generic class to use it in all the program without making N different classes with two fields; for istance in the same class i need an istance of TabellaCustom(string,int) and in another part 
TabellaCustom(char,string)
I need to implement Ienumerable<T> because I need to get this class inside a Combobox binding the DisplayMemberPath property to the class property Contenuto

Comment: @Alex So you want to bind a single instance of this class to the ComboBox so that only one value is shown in the ComboBox? If not, you should not implement `IEnumerable` but simply put your class instances in a list and bind that list to the ComboBox.

Comment: I've tryed to not implement IEnumerable but when I put a list of TabellaCustom(string,string) (for example) in the Combobox.ItemsSource it says that I need to implement IEnumerable<T>
Yes, I need to show just one value (typically the mContenuto value that can be used like a description).
I was thinking to make a TabellaCustom(Of myType, string), maybe in this way is less flexible but usable

Comment: @AlexF A `List(Of TabellaCustom(Of String, String))` implements `IEnumerable(Of TabellaCustom(Of String, String))`, so I don't know where your problem comes from. Nonetheless, I updated my answer with a possible implementation of `GetEnumerator`.